# How to suppress R Shiny's numericInput instant update?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs

I have the following issue with the behaviour of R shiny's numeric input behaviour. Consider the following snippet:

```
ui <- basicPage(
  numericInput("example","Example",value=0),
  verbatimTextOutput("changelog")
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$changelog <- renderPrint(input$example)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Suppose that I want to update the `example` input field to `12345`. My issue is that the default event listener would react to every keystroke. Thus the input field would be set to `1`, `12`,`123` and `1234` before I finally get the desired value of `12345`. Each numeric input set would be followed by an expensive computation - so this is a very undesirable behaviour.

What I am after is modifying this behaviour so that the event listener only reacts to the numeric input when the user hits enter or leaves the input field. I have currently two approaches to this:

1. Use a `reactiveValue` with an update `actionButton` so that the input is updated only when the user clicks update. I find this an inelegant solution and only shirks the original problem without solving it.
2. Modify the local `shiny.js` file directly and remove the `keyup.textInputBinding` event. That creates another issue with running the shiny app on other computers and it would make this modified behaviour uniform for all `numericInput`.

I'm wondering if anyone has a solution/suggestion to this? Preferably something that does not involve changing the local `shiny.js` file. I'm guessing a solution would involve using `shinyjs::runjs` to manually unsubscribe the `keyup.textInputBinding` event - but I don't know enough JavaScript to execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slow frequent invalidation down with `debounce` or `throttle`. In your case, my first guess would be `debounce`: Debouncing means that invalidation is held off for millis milliseconds.

The reactive expression will only be validated until that time window has passed without a subsequent invalidation which may have an effect like this: ooo-oo-oo---- => -----------o-

In your case:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  numericInput("example","Example",value=0),
  verbatimTextOutput("changelogImmediate"),
  verbatimTextOutput("changelog")
)

server <- function(input,output){
  exampleInput <- reactive(input$example) %>% debounce(1000)
  # debouncedExampleInput <- exampleInput

  output$changelogImmediate <- renderPrint(input$example)
  output$changelog <- renderPrint(exampleInput())
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm aware of these methods but as I understand they only delay the event listener by an x amount of milliseconds, right? What I'm aiming is to give the user control when to update the numeric input, namely firing the event only when the user hits enter or leaves the input field.

Comment: It is not an exact solution. To my knowledge it is the only "shiny only" solution. With it's delays it can only alleviate the situation. Why I chose debounce is that it restarts the delay every time it detects a new event while throttle only delays it. That is a bit closer to what you need.